# Laravel - how to use model's ID inside belongs to many relationship query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Models:

```php
Products
Variants
VariantValue

// Product.php
public function variants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Variant::class, 'product_variant', 'product_id', 'variant_id')
        ->with([
            'values' => function ($builder) {
                return $builder->whereHas('products', function ($q) {
                    return $q->where('products.id', $this->id);
                });
            },
        ]);
}


// Variant.php
public function values()
{
    return $this->hasMany(VariantValue::class);
}


// VariantValue.php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_variant_value', 'variant_value_id', 'product_id');
}
```

The above works if we do the following:

```php
Product::first()->variants()->get()->toArray()
```

But, it doe NOT work if we do the following (the values array is empty):

```php
Product::with('variants')->get()->toArray()
```

Meaning the issue is that the product ID is not available inside the belongs to many query:

```php
return $q->where('products.id', $this->id);
```

Any idea how I can make this work? The goal is to load relationship using:

```php
Product::with('variants')->get()
```

Comment: Ok so do you want to retreive variants and its related variant's values along with products?

Comment: OR the product must be exitsts for variant's values too.

Comment: @VivekPawar To be exact, Product variant's, with variant values that belong to the product

Comment: @VivekPawar I do have `product_variant_value` table for connecting products and variant values

Comment: @VivekPawar I just need to include them when fetching products with variants.

Comment: they wont be available ... when eager loading a new model instance is created to call the relationship method to get the builder from it, so there are no attributes

Comment: @lagbox Right, that makes sense. Any idea how I should change the `return $q->where('products.id', $this->id);` part to make it work? I assume what I'm trying to achieve is possible on MySQL, right?

Comment: @CecilyMiller I'm running into the same issue as you are describing. Did you figure out a way to accomplish this? 

In my case I have Users that Have Participations in Funds. So Participations kind of acts like a pivot table. However when using the data I want to loop over a User's Funds and for each Fund I want then to loop over the Participations the User has in that Fund. So in the User Model I want to get the Users Funds with Participations for that User. And not all Participations for that Fund.